# How to split stdout into stdout and stderr with grep?

Tags: shell, grep

My program outputs to stdout. However I want to display some of the output as is and display just the `md5sum` of the rest (testing purposes). I think this ought to be simpler than what I got so far:

```
program | tee >( grep -P 'pattern' >&2 ) | grep -vP 'pattern' | md5sum
```

The regexp `pattern` is long, tedious and constantly changing so I would prefer if I didn't have to repeat it. Best would be if `grep` (or another command that I don't know or think about) had an option for redirecting misses to stderr.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `perl` to match the pattern and write it to standard error stream by just prepending `STDERR` with `print`

```
program | perl -ne '$fh = (/pattern/ ? STDERR : STDOUT); print $fh $_' | md5sum
```

Also because of using `perl`, the PCRE library is built in by default to use under the regular expression match `/../`

Comment: Yes. Or just `program | perl -pe'select/pattern/?STDERR:STDOUT'` (maybe slower for large outputs)